# ActiveMQ Network of Brokers in Java: Some Brokers Doesn't Consume

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In our system there were 2 distributed computers on the same network, each having their own ActiveMQ broker. One of them (broker1)  had only the consumer role, and other  was producing some data on some status topics. We set the ActiveMQ configuration to multicast so that we didn’t need to know the IP addresses of the brokers. (As you’ll see we will add some other consumers step by step and this is where our problems begin) We produce some data at broker2 and monitor them in broker1. Everything was fine.

Than we added a chat feature. We created a “chat” topic and both broker1 and broker2 registered to “chat” as producer and consumer. This worked fine also.

After that, we decided to add a new computer (broker3). We set its ActiveMQ configuration to multicast also. Problem is that, broker3 sends some data to status topics and they can be seen at broker1, but when it comes to “chat”, again all the messages produced for “chat” are seen by broker1 and broker2 but broker3 only consumes the messages produced by itself. It can’t consume the messages on “chat” produced by broker1 and broker2. We set the ActiveMQ configuration of broker3 to static, added both broker1 and broker2 addresses as network connector. This time, broker3 started to monitor the messages coming from itself and from broker1, but it couldn’t monitor the messages coming from broker2. By the way, broker1 and broker2 works the way exactly as we wanted all the time.

And as this problem wasn’t enough, we added one more computer (as broker4) to the network. Neither in multicast nor in static configuration, it could  consume the “chat” messages. Again it only consumed the messages produced by itself. And the data sent by broker4  to status topics could be seen by broker1.

Here’s the configuration of the computers:

- **broker1**: Windows 7, 32 bit, 1.6 JVM, ActiveMQ 5.8.0
- **broker2**: Windows 7, 64 bit, 1.6 32 bit  JVM, ActiveMQ 5.8.0 (registered as 32 bit service)
- **broker3**: Windows XP, 32 bit, 1.6 JVM, ActiveMQ 5.8.0
- **broker4**: Windows 7, 64 bit, 1.6 32 bit JVM, ActiveMQ 5.8.0 (registered as 32 bit service)

As you seen we gave unique names for the brokers, and we turned off Windows firewall on all of the computers (I don’t know if it was related or not but I did).  I also tried registering ActiveMQ service as 64 bit for broker4, but it also didn’t work.

And about the network, in our company there’s a DHCP server, and I have a mini hub on my desk. All the computers I mentioned in scenarios above were obtaining dynamic IP address from the server. When I go through these problems, I plugged-out the server cable from the hub and set all the computers IP addresses as static. But nothing changed. As I said I don’t know if these were related but I tried it anyway.

I don’t know if I’m missing something or doing something wrong. So any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Ekip

Comment: As you are using DHCP on your network you will have to refer to server names, not server IP addresses everywhere.  
All servers will need to subscribe to any multicasts they are interested in, for this purpose they will need to know where multicasts originate from.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But as i explained i plugged-out the server cable from the hub and created my local network. I assigned static IP addresses to the computers where brokers run. But nothing changed in the scenarios.

Comment: Hi, I sinffed the network using wireshark. I started the softwares at broker2 and broker4 in debug mode and put breakpoints to JMS message listener implementations' onMessage() methods. When broker1 sends a message to "chat" topic, both broker2 and broker4 computers receive the message, I can monitor the message as "ActiveMQObjectMessage [Malformed Packet]" (I don't why it is seen as malformed) in wireshark. But when the message is received, software running on broker2 computer stops at the breakpoint, but the software running on broker4 computer doesn't.

Comment: I rechecked the windows firewall settings on broker4 computer. I even try turning the firewall on and allowing the activeMQ wrapper.exe in allowed program list. But it didn't work. I turned off firewall again. I tried every possible solution in my mind and run out of alternatives. So if anybody has any idea to solve this please let me know.